# Error PostgreSQL: "No se pueden insertar varios comandos en una declaración preparada"

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, postgresql-13, firedac

Me encuentro trabajando con PostgreSQL 13.02 y Delphi XE7, utilizando FireDAC, al momento de querer realizar un batch de sentencias obtengo el error:

```
No se pueden insertar varios comandos en una declaración preparada
```

Lo que realizo es lo siguiente:

```
TFDQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO PERSONAS(NOMBRE) VALUES (:NOMBRE);');
TFDQuery.SQL.Add('UPDATE PERSONAS SET APELLIDO=''HERNANDEZ'' WHERE NOMBRE=''JOSE'';');
TFDQuery.AddParam(ftString, 'NOMBRE', ptInput,'JOSE');
TFDQuery.ExecSQL;
```

De acuerdo a la investigación que realice en foros, paginas , etc. se nombra que este problema no se encuentra utilizando un protocolo de conexión 2, FireDAC utiliza el protocolo 3 y me es imposible modificarlo, también encontré que se debía de ajustar el parámetro DirectExecute en true para indicar que no se utilicen sentencias preparadas pero no obtuve ningún cambio el resultado continuo siendo el error, también intente colocar cada sentencia en un bloque anónimo (do begin end) pero ahora el error radicaba en que no encuentra los parámetros aunque estén asignados, no sé si exista alguna otra manera de lograr ejecutar un BATCH de SQL con parámetros que me este faltando probar, espero que me puedan apoyar

Comment: Separar la ejecución en sentencias individuales resolvería el problema.

Comment: Si lo entiendo pero debido a que trabajo en un proyecto que es compatible con SQL Server y Oracle y en ellos si se permite esta ejecución me llevaría a tener que ajustar todas las consultas existentes de esa manera, por eso mi interés en que se pueda resolver con alguna configuración